# How to programatically revert to system proxy settings on Windows?

Tags: windows, proxy

I have my program running on windows which has the option to configure custom proxy settings.
Under the hood, I use `SetInternetOption` with `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` flags, changing the proxy settings for the entire process.

I want to allow users to revert to the default system (INET) proxy setting (as defined in Internet Explorer tools menu -> connections -> LAN settings).

**Is there a way to revert all custom changes made through SetInternetOption and restore the current default system proxy settings?**

**Note**: I thought about querying for the current INET settings and then just manually setting it (with `SetInternetOption`). This solution is not elegant and I'm also worried I might not be able to restore the exact same settings, because for example since IE8 the actual proxy settings may differ from the settings as they are configured in Internet Explorer UI.